# How can I change language on bing speech in bot

Tags: speech-recognition, botframework, bing-speech

I am using bing speech in botframeowrk as below:

```
var speechOptions = 
{
    speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer(
    {
        subscriptionKey: 'YOUR_COGNITIVE_SPEECH_API_KEY'
    }),
    speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer(
    {
        subscriptionKey: 'YOUR_COGNITIVE_SPEECH_API_KEY',
        gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,
        voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaRUS)'
    })
}
```

I want to change language from 'en-us' to some other language, is there any options that i should add like lang:'it-it'.

And also is there a way that i can change languages based on what language user speaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 different items: voice input (SpeechRecognizer) and voice output (SpeechSynthesizer)

### SpeechRecognizer

There is an optional **`locale`** parameter that you can pass like you pass `subscriptionKey`, see [sources](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/CognitiveServices/SpeechRecognition.ts#L6):

```
export interface ICognitiveServicesSpeechRecognizerProperties {
    locale?: string,
    subscriptionKey?: string,
    fetchCallback?: (authFetchEventId: string) => Promise<string>,
    fetchOnExpiryCallback?: (authFetchEventId: string) => Promise<string>
}
```

There is a fallback if none provided ([source](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/CognitiveServices/SpeechRecognition.ts#L29)):

```
const locale = properties.locale || 'en-US';
```

### SpeechSynthesizer

Use **`gender`** and **`voiceName`** parameters ([sources](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/CognitiveServices/SpeechSynthesis.ts#L7)):

```
export interface ICognitiveServicesSpeechSynthesisProperties {
    subscriptionKey?: string,
    gender?: SynthesisGender,
    voiceName?: string,
    fetchCallback?: (authFetchEventId: string) => Promise<string>,
    fetchOnExpiryCallback?: (authFetchEventId: string) => Promise<string>
}
```

For the possible values for those parameters, you can find a list here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/bingvoiceoutput#SupLocales